# Show that $(Meas(X, \Sigma), ||\cdot||_{meas})$ is a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Definition: Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Then, $$Meas(X, \Sigma) = \{ \mu | \mu \text{is a finite signed measure on} (X,\Sigma)\} .$$
>
> Then, we know that  $(Meas(X, \Sigma), ||\cdot||_{meas})$ is a normed  linear space.
>
> Question: Show that it is Banach space.

I am able to show that cauchy sequence, $\mu_n$, in $(Meas(X, \Sigma), ||\cdot||_{meas})$ is also cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$. So, for $E \in \Sigma$, $(\mu_n(E))$ converges uniformly to $\mu(E)$. I can also show that $\mu(E)$ is a finite signed measure.

But, I am having trouble to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}||\mu_n - \mu||_{meas} = 0$.

I think that we have to show something like: for $n \ge N$,
$$||\mu_n - \mu||_{meas} \le \cdot \le |\mu_n(E) - \mu(E)| < \varepsilon.$$

But, I am not sure what should be in this middle section ($\cdot$).

I appreciate if you give some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what definition f norm of a signed measure  you  are using but the Cauchy property implies that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $|\mu_n(A)-\mu_k(A)| <\epsilon$ for all $A$ for $n,k \geq N$. Just let $k \to \infty$ to get $|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)| <\epsilon$ for all $A$ an dthis implies that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the norm. [ If you have defined the  norm using partitions then $\sup_A |\mu(A)| \leq \|\mu\| \leq 2\sup_A |\mu(A)|$ for all real valued countable additive measures $\mu$. This follows immediately from Hahn decomposition of signed measures].

Comment: Sorry. I define $||\mu_n - \mu||_{meas} = |\mu_n - \mu|(X)$. I know that $|\mu_n(X) - \mu(X)| \to 0$, but does this imply that $| \mu_n - \mu|(X) \to 0$? I am confused because $|\mu_n(X) - \mu(X)|\le |\mu_n - \mu|(X)$.

Comment: @Daeseon $|\mu_n(X)-\mu(X)| \to 0$ does not imply $|\mu_n-\mu|(X) \to 0$. But $\sup \{|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)|:A\in \mathcal A\} \to 0$ does imply $|\mu_n-\mu|(X) \to 0$. This can be proved using the Hahn decomposition theorem.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sup\{|\mu_n(A) - \mu(A)| : A \in \mathcal{A}\} \to 0$ imply $|\mu_n - \mu|(X) \to 0$? I cant see the relationship between these two.

Comment: @Daeseon This doesn't follow easily from definitions. I am using the following theorem: if $\mu$ is  a signed measure then there is a measurable set $A$ such that $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$ where $\mu_1(E)=\mu (E\cap A)$ and $\mu_2(E)=\mu (E\cap A^{c})$ are positive measures. From this theorem it follows immediately that  $|\mu |(E) \leq 2 \sup\{|\mu(E)|:A\in \mathcal A\}$.

Comment: Oh... I see. Thanks!